# Gstreamer EOS message handling in filesink to change location on the fly

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

Trying to switch output files on the fly, but can't handle EOS.

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Dynamically-updating-filesink-location-at-run-time-on-the-fly-td4660569.html

Quote:

> Assuming you have a pipeline that looks like this:
>   audiosrc -->  encoder --> mux --> filesink
>
> then you'll need to change it to:
>   audiosrc --> encoder --> queue --> muxsink_bin
>   where muxsink_bin is a bin
>   ghostpad --> mux --> filesink
>
> then the procedure is:
>   1 - Block the queue srcpad using gst_pad_set_blocked_async()
>   2 - In the blocked callback:
>   2a - unlink muxsink_bin with gst_pad_unlink()
>   2b - send an EOS event to the muxsink_bin sink pad with gst_pad_send_event()
>   2b - create a new muxsink_bin
>   2c - set filesink location
>   2d - add the new bin to the pipeline with gst_bin_add()
>   2e - sync with parent using gst_element_sync_state_with_parent()
>   2f - link it to the queue srcpad with gst_pad_link()
>   2g - unblock the queue srcpad with gst_pad_set_blocked_async(). When the unblocked callback occurs you're recording again & no data has been lost. No action is required in the unblocked callback
>
> 3 - handle the EOS & delete the old muxsink_bin. I had a msg handler that I installed in my bin_init() function using "gstbin_class->handle_message = GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR(msg_handler)" & in the handler:
>   3a - lock the bin state with gst_element_set_locked_state()
>   3b - set the state to NULL with gst_element_set_state()
>   3c - remove it from the pipeline with gst_bin_remove()
>
> That's it. The only thing to be mindful of is that data must be flowing thru the pipeline for this to work.
>
> Paddy

The main sequence works except for the finalization of the old pipeline.

The difficulty is with the point 3: I can send EOS to the ghostpad, and the  filesink gets it. But how to catch that EOS?

What does it mean "install msg handler using `gstbin_class->handle_message = GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR(msg_handler)`"?

Answer (score 4):

There is message forwarding.

Must be enabled on the bus:

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(bin), "message-forward", TRUE, 0);
```

Handling:

```
case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
{
    const GstStructure *s = gst_message_get_structure (msg);

    if (gst_structure_has_name (s, "GstBinForwarded"))
    {
        GstMessage *forward_msg = NULL;

        gst_structure_get (s, "message", GST_TYPE_MESSAGE, &forward_msg, NULL);
        if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (forward_msg) == GST_MESSAGE_EOS)
        {
            g_print ("EOS from element %s\n",
                    GST_OBJECT_NAME (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (forward_msg)));
            DestroyBin();
            CreateNewBin();
            RemovePad();
        }
        gst_message_unref (forward_msg);
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
static gchar *opt_effects = NULL;

#define DEFAULT_EFFECTS "identity,exclusion,navigationtest," \
        "agingtv,videoflip,vertigotv,gaussianblur,shagadelictv,edgetv"

static GstElement *pipeline;
static GstElement * muxer;
static GstElement * sink;
static GstElement * q2;
static int i=0;
GstElement * bin;
GstPad * muxerSinkPad;

gulong probeId;

static GQueue effects = G_QUEUE_INIT;

void CreateNewBin();
void DestroyBin();
void ChangeLocation();
void RemovePad();

static GstPadProbeReturn
pad_probe_cb (GstPad * pad, GstPadProbeInfo * info, gpointer user_data)
{
    GstPad *sinkPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(bin, "sink");
    gst_pad_unlink(pad, sinkPad);
    gst_pad_send_event(sinkPad, gst_event_new_eos());
    gst_object_unref(sinkPad);

    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

static gboolean
timeout_cb (gpointer user_data)
{
    static int i=0;
    if(i==0)
    {
        GstPad * q2SrcPad;
        q2SrcPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q2, "src");
        std::cout << "Timeout: " << q2SrcPad << std::endl;

        probeId = gst_pad_add_probe (q2SrcPad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM,
                pad_probe_cb, user_data, NULL);
        gst_object_unref(q2SrcPad);

        return TRUE;
    }
return FALSE;
}

static gboolean
bus_cb (GstBus * bus, GstMessage * msg, gpointer user_data)
{
    GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop*)user_data;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:{
        GError *err = NULL;
        gchar *dbg;

        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &dbg);
        gst_object_default_error (msg->src, err, dbg);
        g_error_free (err);
        g_free (dbg);
        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
        break;
    }
    case GST_EVENT_EOS:
        std::cout << "EOS message is got" << std::endl;
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:
    {
        const GstStructure *s = gst_message_get_structure (msg);

        if (gst_structure_has_name (s, "GstBinForwarded"))
        {
            GstMessage *forward_msg = NULL;

            gst_structure_get (s, "message", GST_TYPE_MESSAGE, &forward_msg, NULL);
            if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (forward_msg) == GST_MESSAGE_EOS)
            {
                g_print ("EOS from element %s\n",
                        GST_OBJECT_NAME (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (forward_msg)));
                DestroyBin();
                CreateNewBin();
                RemovePad();
            }
            gst_message_unref (forward_msg);
        }
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    GError *err = NULL;
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstElement *src, *q1,/* *q2,*/ /**effect,*/ /**filter1*//*, *filter2*/ *encoder;/*, *sink*/;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");

    src = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", NULL);

    //Create a caps filter between videosource videoconvert
    std::string capsString = "video/x-raw,format=YV12,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1";
    GstCaps * dataFilter = gst_caps_from_string(capsString.c_str());

    q1 = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", NULL);

    encoder = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", NULL);

    q2 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, q1, encoder, q2, 0);
    gboolean link = gst_element_link_filtered(src, q1, dataFilter);
    link &= gst_element_link(q1, encoder);
    link &= gst_element_link(encoder, q2);

    CreateNewBin();

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    gst_bus_add_watch (GST_ELEMENT_BUS (pipeline), bus_cb, loop);

    g_timeout_add_seconds (10, timeout_cb, loop);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);

    return 0;
}

void RemovePad()
{
    GstPad * q2SrcPad;
    q2SrcPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q2, "src");
    gst_pad_remove_probe(q2SrcPad, probeId);
    gst_object_unref(q2SrcPad);
}

void DestroyBin()
{
    gst_element_set_state(bin, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(pipeline), bin);
}

void CreateNewBin()
{

    static std::string fileLocPattern = "deneme%d.mkv";
    char buffer[12];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    sprintf(buffer, fileLocPattern.c_str(), i++);

    //Create Muxer Element
    muxer = gst_element_factory_make("matroskamux", "MatroskaMuxer");

    //Create File Sink Element
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", buffer);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink), "location", buffer, 0);

    //Create muxsinkBin
    bin = gst_bin_new(buffer);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(bin), "message-forward", TRUE, 0);
    //Add a src pad to the bin
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(bin), muxer, sink, 0);

    gboolean linkState = TRUE;
    //Connect elements within muxsink_bin
    //Link: matroskamuxer -> filesink
    linkState &= gst_element_link_many(muxer, sink, 0);

    //Add this bin to pipeline
    gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), bin);

    //Create ghostpad and manually link muxsinkBin and remaining part of the pipeline
    {
        GstPadTemplate * muxerSinkPadTemplate;


        if( !(muxerSinkPadTemplate = gst_element_class_get_pad_template(GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS(muxer), "video_%u")) )
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to get source pad template from muxing element" << std::endl;
        }

        //Obtain dynamic pad from element
        muxerSinkPad = gst_element_request_pad(muxer, muxerSinkPadTemplate, 0, 0);

        //Add ghostpad
        GstPad * ghostPad = gst_ghost_pad_new("sink", muxerSinkPad);
        gst_element_add_pad(bin, ghostPad);
        gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(muxerSinkPad));

        gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(bin);

        //Get src pad from queue element
        GstPad * queueBeforeBinSrcPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q2, "src");

        //Link queuebeforebin to ghostpad
        if (gst_pad_link(queueBeforeBinSrcPad, ghostPad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK )
        {

            std::cout << "QueueBeforeBin cannot be linked to MuxerSinkPad." << std::endl;
        }
        gst_object_unref(queueBeforeBinSrcPad);
    }
}
```

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Listening-on-EOS-events-for-GstBin-td4669126.html

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/file/n4669476/main.cpp

Comment: With Gstreamer 1.8.3, this code gave me errors `'GST_IS_ELEMENT (dest)' failed` and print `QueueBeforeBin cannot be linked to MuxerSinkPad.`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PierreOlivier, I don't know, it's not in my code any more. I've posted my `plisolatedbin` implementation as another answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478434/4742108. It's probably the class that is dealing with these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case you can use `multifilesink` element. It will switch files on the fly on certain events. A file for each buffer, a file for each segment... Check its properties and see if there is anything that would work for you.

It also serves as a good code base in case you want to write something similar (or maybe extend it?)

Comment: I've considered that. Two problems: file naming is not good enough (I need dates in my preferred format), can't control segmentation: DISCONT buffers are no longer DISCONT when they reach multifilesink, keyframe option relies on some video elements (I'm doing audio). About extending: I'm not sure if I can implement a dialog with a generic muxer to give correct eos for all parts. Also, subclassing is terrifying, I don't yet understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the code of actual custom GstBin aka 'muxsink_bin' that I ended up implementing to do that forwarding and EOS handling for the 'detachable sink part' of the pipeline.

plisolatedbin.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/gstbin.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#define PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN             (pl_isolated_bin_get_type ())
#define PL_IS_ISOLATED_BIN(obj)          (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE ((obj), PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN))
#define PL_IS_ISOLATED_BIN_CLASS(klass)  (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE ((klass), PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN))
#define PL_ISOLATED_BIN_GET_CLASS(obj)   (G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_CLASS ((obj), PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN, PlIsolatedBinClass))
#define PL_ISOLATED_BIN(obj)             (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((obj), PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN, PlIsolatedBin))
#define PL_ISOLATED_BIN_CLASS(klass)     (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST ((klass), PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN, PlIsolatedBinClass))
#define PL_ISOLATED_BIN_CAST(obj)        ((PlIsolatedBin*)(obj))

typedef struct _PlIsolatedBin PlIsolatedBin;
typedef struct _PlIsolatedBinClass PlIsolatedBinClass;

/**
 * Does not forward EOS to parent by default.
 */
struct _PlIsolatedBin
{
    GstBin bin;
};

struct _PlIsolatedBinClass
{
    GstBinClass parent_class;
};

GType pl_isolated_bin_get_type();
GstElement* pl_isolated_bin_new();

G_END_DECLS
```

plisolatedbin.c:

```
#include "plisolatedbin.h"

#include <assert.h>

G_DEFINE_TYPE(PlIsolatedBin, pl_isolated_bin, GST_TYPE_BIN)

static void pl_isolated_bin_init(PlIsolatedBin *plisolatedbin)
{
}

static void pl_isolated_bin_handle_message_func(GstBin *bin, GstMessage *message)
{
    if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message) != GST_MESSAGE_EOS)
    {
        GST_BIN_CLASS(pl_isolated_bin_parent_class)->handle_message(bin, message);
    }
    else
    {
        GstMessage *forwarded = gst_message_new_element(GST_OBJECT_CAST(bin), gst_structure_new("PlIsolatedBinForwarded", "message", GST_TYPE_MESSAGE, message, NULL));
        gst_element_post_message(GST_ELEMENT_CAST(bin), forwarded);
    }
}

static void pl_isolated_bin_class_init(PlIsolatedBinClass *class)
{
    class->parent_class.handle_message = GST_DEBUG_FUNCPTR(pl_isolated_bin_handle_message_func);
}

GstElement* pl_isolated_bin_new()
{
    return g_object_new(PL_TYPE_ISOLATED_BIN, NULL);
}
```